# how to use jquery to do a series of position changes on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html, slider

I would like to be able to set some animations on a set of divs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(".nextwp").click(function(){
    $('.welcome').animate({
        left: "-9999px"
    }, 8500);
    $('.welcome').animate({
        right: "-=9999px"
    }, 0);

    $('.work').animate({
        right: "+0px"
    }, 1300);
});
```

I want the .welcome class div to move to the left for a duration of 8.5 seconds until it is hidden from view.  Then I need to reset it's position to right of -9999px.  It is not reseting for some reason.  Am I going about this the right way?  Once it's position is set to -9999px I need the work class div to slide in from the right.

Let me know if you need more info.

The problem is that the welcome class div never gets it's position set to -9999px for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

(basically a simple custom slider)

Comment: Put the second animation in a callback function of the first animation

Comment: How would I do that?  I am not familiar with javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you think about this approach what you're really telling it to do is to animate 9999px in 8.5 seconds, I wouldn't expect this to behave consistently.

The easy option would be to use the effects module of jQuery UI and use `$el.show('slide')`.

If you want something custom, then your best bet would be to create a container with `overflow: hidden` and slide the element till it gets out of view. This would be far more predictable and will perform way better.

Comment: It does slide to the left, and the overflow is set to hidden.  I have a series of divs set up to behave in this manner but I want the user to be able to select "start over" at the end of the slideshow and have the whole thing reset.  As well as on each slide they should be able to go to the previous slide.  The whole reason I didn't go with a pre made slider is that I wanted custom next and prev links per each slide.